# How to find the index of last element on list and add it to another

Tags: python

I'm working on a program and what the point of this program is:

1. Count the number of households included in the survey and print it in a three-column format.
2. Calculate the average household income, and list the identification number and income of each household that exceeds the average.
3. Determine the percentage of households that have incomes below the 2015 United States’ Contiguous States poverty level. Compute the poverty level income using the formula given. The formula is within the *povertycalc* function assigned the variable called *povertyLevel*.

The issue is this, im trying to make a list of indexes of another list of houses that fall below the poverty line.

```
def main():
    NumberofHouseholds = 0
    inFile = open('program9.txt', 'r')
    HouseIncome = []
    global HouseIncome
    avgincome = 0

    lineRead = inFile.readline()       # Read first record
    while lineRead != '':              # While there are more records
       words = lineRead.split()        # Split the records into substrings
       acctNum = int(words[0])         # Convert first substring to integer
       annualIncome = float(words[1])  # Convert second substring to float
       members = int(words[2])         # Convert third substring to integer
       global members
       global annualIncome
       print(acctNum, format(annualIncome, '.2f'), members, sep=' ')
       HouseIncome.append(annualIncome)
       povertycalc()
       NumberofHouseholds = NumberofHouseholds + 1
       avgincome = (avgincome+annualIncome)/NumberofHouseholds
       lineRead = inFile.readline()    # Read next record

    # Close the file.
    inFile.close() # Close file
    print(avgincome)
    print(HouseIncome)

def povertycalc():
    indexKeep = []
    global indexKeep
    m = members
    povertyLevel = 15930.00 + 4160.00 * (m-2)
    if annualIncome < povertyLevel:
        indexKeep.append(HouseIncome.index(HouseIncome[-1])) #Finds most recent index of household in HouseIncome and adds it to list indexKeep
    print(indexKeep) #not printing the new value added to indexKeep

# Call the main function.
main()
```

When I emailed my professor yesterday I was told:

> "You cannot use another list's data as an index."

What should I do to make this more efficient? As of now, the program prints out the three columns of the information given (I will post a link for the TXT file associated with this program) and a blank bracket of what is supposed to contain the list of houses below the poverty line.

Below is the text in the file associated with the program:

```
1042  12180.06  3
1062  13240.45  2
1327  19800.56  2
1483  22458.23  7
1900  17000.09  3
2112  18125  4
2345  15623  2
3210   3200  1
3600  39500  5
3601  11970  2
4724   8900  3
6217  45000.70  2
9280   6200  1
1000  31000  3
1200  36000  2
5601  51970  9
5724  66900  3
5217  10002.68  2
5280  70000  1
5000 100000  6
5200  25000.4  3
5230 120000  6
6641  85000  7
7000  45500  4
7100  56500  3
8110 110005.9  8
9101  67590.40 6
```

Comment: So, i should be able to calculate if it's below the line and if it is i would what? Add that house to a list to print later?

Comment: You can go about this without using globals.. and you should.  Don't use globals.  Pass information through the function parameters and your issue should be solved.  Don't use globals.... please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in Your code snippet, several problems are there.

You may be thinking that declaring a `global` variable makes that variable as `global` to that script!. But that's not actually happens
You miss interpreted the `global` keyword.
By using `global` statement you tell the python interpreter that you want to access/ modify the variable which is in the outer scope instead of assigning it to locally.
However minimal use of `global` statement is a good programming design.

In the code fragment `indexKeep.append(HouseIncome.index(HouseIncome[-1]))`, the `HouseIncome[-1]` extracts the last value of the list. Thereby incorporating `HouseIncome.index(HouseIncome[-1])` gives the index of last element, which you are doing it indirectly. Instead you can simply find `len(HouseIncome) - 1` to get the same. But the `HouseIncome` you are referring to is the one that you have initialized at the top which is empty. so that will ultimately not work.

I've modified your program a bit. But I have not tested it. May be you wanna look at that.

```
def main():
    NumberofHouseholds = 0
    HouseIncome = []
    avgincome = 0

    for idNumber, row in enumerate(open('program9.txt', 'r')): # While there are more records
        words = row.split()        # Split the records into substrings
        acctNum = int(words[0])         # Convert first substring to integer
        annualIncome = float(words[1])  # Convert second substring to float
        members = int(words[2])         # Convert third substring to integer
        print(acctNum, format(annualIncome, '.2f'), members, sep=' ')
        if povertycalc(annualIncome, idNumber + 1):
            HouseIncome.append(annualIncome)
        NumberofHouseholds = NumberofHouseholds + 1
        avgincome = (avgincome+annualIncome)/NumberofHouseholds

    # Close the file.
    print(avgincome)
    print(HouseIncome)

def povertycalc(annualIncome, members):
    povertyLevel = 15930.00 + 4160.00 * (members-2)

    if annualIncome < povertyLevel:
        return True
    else: return False

# Call the main function.
main()
```